# Azure Devops Deployment using ci cd

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Any idea how to deploy adf pipelines using devops ci cd if arm template parameter exceed 256

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters section of the template, you specify which values you can input when deploying the resources. You're limited to 256 parameters in a template. **You can reduce the number of parameters by using objects that contain multiple properties.**

```
"parameters": {
  "<parameter-name>" : {
    "type" : "<type-of-parameter-value>",
    "defaultValue": "<default-value-of-parameter>",
    "allowedValues": [ "<array-of-allowed-values>" ],
    "minValue": <minimum-value-for-int>,
    "maxValue": <maximum-value-for-int>,
    "minLength": <minimum-length-for-string-or-array>,
    "maxLength": <maximum-length-for-string-or-array-parameters>,
    "metadata": {
      "description": "<description-of-the parameter>"
    }
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax